# raspberry pi mongodb help connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, raspberry-pi

So I am just gettting into web dev and as i've been following along with colt steele's course on udemy. The class is going swell and I am building my own website on the side which I am trying to host on a raspberry pi 4 (I have a 32 bit version as well as the new 64 bit version). I have the web app and database working fine locally on my win10 laptop, but I cannot get the app to work on my pi. I am using Node v12.18.3, express v4.17.1, and mongodb v4.4 (shell and server, win10 machine), and mongodb v2.4.14(raspberry pi).

the problem I seem to be having is connecting to the mongo database. I think this is cause I'm using mongoose to try to connect to mongodb but mongoose wont support mongodb version 2.4.14.

this is my code that works on my win 10 machine to connect:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Fries-and-Ketchup', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('connected to mongoDB');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error' , err => {
    console.log('error connecting to mongodb');
});
```

this is the error i get in my terminal:

```
(node:31771) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerSelectionError: Server at localhost:27017 reports maximum wire version 0, but this version of the Node.js Driver requires at least 2 (MongoDB 2.6)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/pi/Fries_and_ketchup/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
(node:31771) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:31771) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

so I tried using a different piece of code I found but unfortunately this doesnt work either:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://10.0.0.109:27017";

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Fries-and-ketchup", {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
 })
```

how can I connect to the Mongo database on the Pi?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it rigth, but please check your mongodb version with :

```
mongo --version
```

if this version is < 3.1.0 update your mongo version to => 3.1.0 and use this connection code:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Fries-and-ketchup", {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
 })
```

or even use mongoose driver, if you want to keep your actual mongo db version(2.x.x), try to connect like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Fries-and-ketchup', function(err, db) {console.log("connect",db)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Fries-and-ketchup";

const client = new MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Since MongoClient is a class, you need to declare it with `new`